# Count Black Pixels of Image

Tags: php, image, count, png

I am trying to count only the black pixels of a PNG image using PHP.  Have not found anything close on the web. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read all the pixels iteratively and increment the counter?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's your application of this? This seems kind of odd for a homework problem. :D

Comment: Would you have a quick code snipplet?

Comment: What's the use of this? There may well be a better solution to the actual problem than counting the black pixels.

Comment: Need to compare simple shapes to other shapes... all images are black pixels on a white background...

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the Imagick extension, in particular Imagick::getImageTotalInkDensity() sounds like a much cheaper option.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that using gd. Just open the image with [`imageCreateFromPNG()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php), get the image size with `imagesx()` and `imagesy()` and then loop over all pixels and do [`imageColorAt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php).

Comment: Not a homework assignment, need to write the code for custom mobile app I am working on...

Comment: I wasn't assuming it is a homework assignment ^^. If you are referring to the fact that code will probably not be very fast I would propose you have a look at [ImageMagick](http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.imagick.php). You can definitely do some magic with that ;). It will also allow you to substract one image from another etc, so you can do image comparison. See [this example] (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php)

Comment: Problem is app is needs to compare 5+ images at the same time... and get a percetage difference from each...

Comment: Just use compare - if you want multithreading you can call it from the command line and have multiple running at once. Then you can use [identifiy](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) to get statistical information into php.